# What is the error function in multi-class classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic-regression

I am in trouble to know what is the loss function of a neural network. For a binary classification problem, is it mean squared error, as described in the following video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u0jaA3qAGk&t=59s or is it cross entropy as defined here http://work.caltech.edu/slides/slides09.pdf and why ?

Moreover, in case of multi classification, I think there is sth like softmax but I don't really know how it works. Could s.o. explain me properly ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please copy the definition to your question. I'm on mobile and I can't access it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Softmax is the activation function, not the loss. Softmax is defined as ([source](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nonlinearities.html)):

$$\varphi(\mathbf{x})_j = \frac{e^{\mathbf{x}_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^K e^{\mathbf{x}_k}}$$

The cross entropy is also defined for multiple classes (and multiple labels):

$$E_{-x} = - \sum_{k}[t_k^x \log(o_k^x) + (1-t_k^x) \log (1- o_k^x)]$$

Where k is the class, o is the output of the classifier and t is the true label. The x superscript indicates that it belongs to x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; could you also provide some explanation about softmax, please (formula + comment). Thanks !

Comment: I've added the formula. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function for explanations.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it seems quite clear